# What should be logged in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, error-logging, loggly

We are starting out a new Nodejs project, and I am working on wiring up Winston to Loggly.

Since we are new to node, my question is, what is typically information that should be logged and in what format for Loggly to accept it? What do you guys find helpful when going through the logs, i.e, remote address, method where error happend, etc... ?

Comment: This question is far too broad.  What to log is pretty much specific to your application.  You log exceptional things (things that probably shouldn't be happening that you might want to know about) and you log things that you might want to collect statistics on later and you add temporary logging when trying to track down an intermittent problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Ultimate Guide to Logging in Node](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/category/node/) give some some good ideas you can use as a starting point. It also gives you tips on how to troubleshoot common problems. I helped put the team together to write it. It's an open source guide, and we take suggestions on topics and content from the community.